# Tooltip on button click Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I want to show a tooltip with the message "Copied!" when the button is clicked and make it disappear after a few seconds. Most of the answers I saw was using jQuery, is there a way to make it on Vue.js without too much resources?

My button is made and already have a function that onClick copy a code and I can use this function to show the tooltip as well.

I was thinking in something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;

  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
</style>
<body style="text-align:center;">

<h2>Basic Tooltip</h2>

<p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>

<p>Note that the position of the tooltip text isn't very good. Go back to the tutorial and continue reading on how to position the tooltip in a desirable way.</p>

</body>
</html>

 copyClick(code) { 
   const payload = {
     document: --- , 
     id: ---,
     status: ---,
   }
   Service.saveEvent ({payload});
   ClipboardService.copy(code) 
}
```

Comment: @BlockchainOffice I can't share it since it's corporative, but it's a Vue.js Component and a regular button with a simple function. I'm going to add the main part of the function in the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try like in following snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      tool: false,
      text: "Copied!"
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showTool() {
      this.tool = true
      setTimeout(() => this.tool = false, 3000)
    },
    copyClick() {
      this.showTool()
      // your code
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;

  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -.5rem;
  right: -8rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo" style="text-align:center;">
  <button @click="copyClick">Copy</button>
  <h2>Basic Tooltip</h2>
  <p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>
  <div @mouseover="showTool" class="tooltip">Hover over me
    <span v-show="tool" class="tooltiptext">{{ text }}</span>
  </div>
  <p>Note that the position of the tooltip text isn't very good. Go back to the tutorial and continue reading on how to position the tooltip in a desirable way.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Nikola! I used your response as a guide.